# UI-Router 1.0 redirect based on a user role

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm upgrading to `ui-router@1.0.0-beta.2` and trying to figure out what is the best way to redirect user to a different state if he doesn't have necessary permissions.

This is what I have:

```
.state('company_dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    controller: 'CompanyDashboardCtrl',
    resolve: {
        user: function(UserService) {
            return UserService.getActiveUser();
        },
        company: function(UserService) {
            return CompanyService.getActiveCompany();
        },
        permissions: function(CompanyService, user, company){
            return CompanyService.getUserPermissions(company, user);
        }
    },
    onEnter: function($state, permissions) {
        if (permissions.canAccessDashboard === false)
            return $state.go('company_landing_page');
    }
})
```

The above example works, but it logs the following error: `TransitionRejection(type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#1( ''{} -> 'company_landing_page'{} ))` which makes me think, there should be a better way.

Side question, is it the good practice to check permissions during the `resolve`?

**UPDATE:**

Changing `$state.go()` to `$state.target()` helped me to get rid of the console error. [This comment](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2450#issuecomment-170413745) has helped.
Though the question stands, whether I'm doing it it the right place?

Comment: I used to check permission on template as built by spring or something backend framework, I think checking permission on frontend is not good because everyone can see the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a data property to your state as follows:

```
.state('company_dashboard', {
    data: {
           requiresAuthentication: true
    }
}
```

And then:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
        // Check if user is authenticated
        // And route requires authentication
       if (!toState.data.requiresAuthentication) {
            $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
       } else if (user && toState.data.requiresAuthentication) {
            $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
       } else {
            $state.go('login');
       }
    });
});
```

This seems to work quite well even if I am sure it can be more polished, but I hope this gives you an idea on how you may proceed.