# Secret link routing with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, routes

The concept is this:

When the administrator logs in successfully (from `admin.html`) he is redirected to a page called `adminMenu.html`. Now since I need to put the `adminMenu.html` in the routing, users may obviously access this page from the address bar.

```
app.controller('adminCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.chkCredentials = function(information) {
    $http.post('php/getLogin.php', information).success(function(data) {
        if (data == true) {
            alert("Logged in.");
                $location.path("/adminMenu"); //go to admin page
        } else {
        alert("Incorrect Credentials!");
        }
    }); 
}
});
```

How do I make it such that the page is "available for access", when the data is `true` from the above code?

This is my routing just in case needed.

```
   var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
    templateUrl : "home.html"
})
.when("/proverbs", {
    templateUrl : "proverbs.html"

})
.when("/comments", {
    templateUrl : "comments.html"
})
.when("/admin", {
    templateUrl: "admin.html"
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo:"/home"
})
});
```

Thanks and my apologies since I'm new for this.

Comment: I use ui-router and solved in this way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475916/ui-router-1-0-redirect-based-on-a-user-role/39949753#39949753 Hope that helps!